# can't download cvs projects from dev.eclipse.org

Tags: eclipse, cvs, transform, equinox, p2

I'm trying to download projects from a cvs repository.
The repository is taken from `:pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:443/cvsroot/eclipse` but I can't download anything for an

> Error validating location: "Could not connect to :pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/443/cvsroot/eclipse: I/O exception occured: ProxyHTTP: java.io.IOException: proxy error: Proxy Authentication Required (The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )"

How can I solve this? I need to download these projects because I need the org.eclipse.equinox.transforms.xslt.plugin bundle to do the "How To Package Transformers for Distribution" part of the [Equinox Transforms](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Transforms) guide.
If you know where can I download this plugin without doing this mess you're welcome.

If i don't insert the 443 port number but the default Eclipse gives me another error:

> Error validating location: "Could not connect to :pserver:anonymous@dev.eclipse.org:/443/cvsroot/eclipse: I/O exception occured: ProxyHTTP: java.io.IOException: proxy error: Proxy Error (The Specified Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) port is not allowed. ISA Server is not configured to allow SSL requests from this port. Most Web browsers use port 443 for SSL requests. )"

For this error I find that I need ISAtrpe to add a port number to ISA Firewall but after the installation (I read that must be done ON ISA Firewall but how???) I find that default ports that I must have (443) there aren't.
But to me this isn't the right solution for the first problem above.

I tried also with tortoise but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to talk to your local system administrator; your ISA implementation is a mess.

Comment: Thank you Ernest for your answer but I don't understand well. With ISAtrpe I can add another port to allow SSL requests, can I resolve the problem without to talk with system administrator in this way? However I don't understand the reason why I can't see default ports on isatrpe.